# React component being called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

The `Portal` component is being called twice.

Why is it happening?

How can I prevent that?

---

`index.js`

```
const App = () => {
  const theme = lightTheme;

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <StyleSheetManager>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Portal />
          </BrowserRouter>
          <GlobalStyle />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </StyleSheetManager>
    </Provider>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

`Portal.jsx`

```
class Portal extends React.Component {
  isAuthenticated = () => {
    if (this.props.tokenized) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Sidebar />
          <MainContainer />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/"></Route>
          </Switch>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    } else {
      return <Authorize />;
    }
  };

  render() {
    this.props.dispatch(checkToken());
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Alerts />
        {this.isAuthenticated()}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  ({ authenticator }) => ({
    tokenized: authenticator.tokenized,
  }),
  null
)(Portal);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens as you're dispatching an action on every render and the redux state is probably getting updated after the first dispatch call to it.

When your `Portal` renders for the first time, yu dispatch `checkToken()` which checks for token probably and updates `authenticator.tokenized`. Since your component is connected to the store to map state to props, your prop `tokenized` carries a new value therefore causing a re-render. BUT, rendering twice of this particular component is not erronuous as the token can be only avilable after some time(after the first render of the component).

You should memoize the component so that you can perform checks to incoming props with previous props to avoid unnecessary re-renders.

Also, your checkToken call should happen only once when the component loads (in `componentDidMount`) and not everytime in each render method execution.

Comment: How do I memorize the component?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Read about React's memoization for class components.

Comment: `componentDidMount` totally fixed the issue. Thanks!